# PyQt5 QButtonGroup() как передать имя нажатой кнопки в функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

пишу непобедимые крестики нолики и столкнулся с проблемой:

```
self.btn_grp = QButtonGroup()
self.btn_grp.setExclusive(True)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_6, id = 6)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_7, id = 7)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_2, id = 2)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_1, id = 1)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_5, id = 5)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_9, id = 9)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_8, id = 8)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_3, id = 3)
self.btn_grp.addButton(self.pushButton_4, id = 4)
self.btn_grp.checkedId()
self.btn_grp.buttonClicked.connect(self.pressed())
```

как мне передать имя нажатой кнопки через conect в функцию
или хотябы id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для получения [id кнопки](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#id) и ее [текста](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#text-prop)

*Обратите внимание, что подправил код коннекта, т.к. туда нужно передавать ссылку на функцию, а не результат ее выполнения*

Попробуйте:

```
    ...
    self.btn_grp.buttonClicked.connect(self.pressed)

def pressed(self, button):
    print(self.btn_grp.id(button), button.text())
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Alexalexeev, пожалуйста :) Не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: я не могу проголосовать это мой первый вопрос, но как только будет достаточно репутации обязательно проголосую, а ответ уже принял :)

Comment: @Alexalexeev, благодарю за ответственность, хех :)

Comment: еще немного осталось)

Comment: готово! :))))))

Comment: @Alexalexeev, спасибо :D